# How to add text(uilabel)in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, uilabel

I'm doing one application in that,i'm playing two videos one after another using MPMoviePlayerController.After the first video played in the middle of the second video it shows blank screen(white screen).At the time i want to display some text it simply says Loading...by using UILabel.Instead of white screen i want to display the text .

How can i do this.

Any ideas please..

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MPMoviePlayerController has a property `view`. Just add your UILabel as a subview of that view.

You'd also want to listen for the appropriate notifications to know when the second movie started to play so you could remove your UILabel. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) for details.

Comment: @Anomie:Thank you for your quick reply Anomie.How can i use view property of MPMoviePlayerController for adding label.I have already use the notification for finding(first video start,first video end,second video start and second video end.

Comment: The view property is a UIView. So you use `addSubview:` on it just as you would with any other view.

Comment: @Anomie:Like this i want to add ah?[myView addSubview: [player view]];

Comment: @Anomie:i'm not clear about this please give me a sample code.please guide me Anomie..

Comment: @Anomie:Is this correct?[moviePlayerController.view addSubview:myLabel];  please explain me..

Answer (score 0):

To add the label as sub view of the movie player

```
[[player view] addSubview:label];
```

Comment: I'm adding like this only.But,it displays the text in the view only not in player.